# Sed: Deleting all content matching a pattern

Tags: macos, mac, unix, sed, plist

I have some plist files on Mac OS X that I would like to shrink. They have a lot of `<dict>` with `<key>` and values. One of these keys is a thumbnail which has a `<data>` value with base64 encoded binary (I think). I would like to remove this key and value.

I was thinking this could maybe be done by sed, but I don't really know how to use it and it seems like sed only works on a line-by-line basis?

Either way I was hoping someone could help me out. In the file I would like to delete everything that matches the following pattern or something close to that:

```
<key>Thumbnail<\/key>[^<]*<\/data>
```

In the file it looks like this:

```
            // Other keys and values

            <key>Thumbnail</key>
            <data>
            TU0AKgAAOEi25Pqx3/ip2fak0vOdzPCVxu2RweuPv+mLu+mIt+aGtuaEtOSB

            ...

            dCBBcHBsZSBDb21wdXRlciwgSW5jLiwgMjAwNQAAAAA=
            </data>

            // Other keys and values
```

Anyone know how I could do this? Also, if there are any better tools that I can use in the terminal to do this, I would like to know about that as well :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two utilities available on the command line specifically devoted to working with preference list files: `defaults` (in `/usr/bin`) and `PlistBuddy` in (`/usr/libexec`).

**Still using `sed`**:

`sed` does allow a multiple line delete using the `D` instead of the `d` flag.

eg. `sed -e '/<key>Thumbnail<\/key>/,  /<\/data>/D' < /PATH/TO/FILE.txt` removes all instances of the key Thumbnail and it's associated data.

**Using `defaults`**:

`defaults delete /PATH/TO/PLIST "Thumbnail"`. Do not include the `.plist` extension as part of the path. Also, this will only work on root level items in a `.plist`, so if the Thumbnail key is inside another array or dict it won't work.

**Using `PlistBuddy`**:

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :Thumbnail" /PATH/TO/PLIST.plist`. If the Thumbnail key is nested, you can append the path before it if you know it. eg. `PlistBuddy -c "Delete :User:Thumbnail"` if the Thumbnail entry was in a User dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this with sed, but it would be difficult.  Perl could do this more easily.  The guts of the perl script would be:

```
undef $/; # This allows reading in of all lines in one swoop

$contents = <>; # Read in contents of file (specified on command line)

$contents = s{<key>Thumbnail</key>.*?</data>}{}s;

print $contents;
```

If you had the above in a perl script called change.plx and you had your data in a file called keyfile, then you could fix up that file by doing:

```
$ perl change.plx keyfile > /tmp/$$ && cat /tmp/$$ > keyfile && rm /tmp/$$
```

Of course, make sure you have a backup of any file that you do this to.  It's possible to do all this work on multiple files with a single one line perl program on the command line like this:

```
$ perl -p0777i -e 's{<key>Thumbnail</key>.*?</data>}{}s;' file file file ...
```

---

Marnix

Comment: Something was deleted from my regular expressions.  I'm new to this site and I'm guessing that any html-like expressions need to be escaped.  The regular expression was supposed to be (hopefully it will work in this comment):

  s{Thumbnail.*?</data>}{}s

Marnix

Comment: You need to indent your code example with 4 spaces. Think there also is a code button above the editor that you can click while having your code selected.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is an awesome command line tool for manipulating XML. The main problems with it are 1) it's a *very* complex tool (since it does very complex jobs), and 2) you'd probably have to build it for OS X yourself.

Answer (score 0):

use awk, not sed

```
$ cat file
asdkf
asdklf
            // Other keys and values

            <key>Thumbnail</key>
            <data>
            TU0AKgAAOEi25Pqx3/ip2fak0vOdzPCVxu2RweuPv+mLu+mIt+aGtuaEtOSB

            ...

            dCBBcHBsZSBDb21wdXRlciwgSW5jLiwgMjAwNQAAAAA=
            </data>

            // Other keys and values

ksdf

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="</data>"} /<key>/{ gsub("<key>.*</key>|<data>.*","") }1' file
asdkf
asdklf
            // Other keys and values





            // Other keys and values

ksdf
```

the statement says, use `</data>` as record separator,  then replace tags `<key>` and `<data>` with nothing, when `<key>` is found in the record